# Datatables doesnt detect JSON have been read with Angular

Tags: json, ajax, angular, datatable, datatables

I am reading a JSON from a server with Angular to display it with Datatables.
I read the file correctly and is put into the table, but the functionalities of Datatables don't work, It says that "No data available in table" and "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries", but the data is there.

The plugin and its dependancies are correctly installed and imported.

here is the json file:
http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

-- empleado.ts

```
export class Empleado{
    id :number;
    employee_name :string;
    employee_salary :number;
    employee_age :number;
    profile_image :string;
}
```

-- leer-empleados.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Empleado } from './empleado';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import{Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LeerEmpleadosService {
  private urlFichero = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';

  getEmpleados() :Observable<Empleado[]> {
    return this.http.get<Empleado[]>(this.urlFichero);
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

-- empleados.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LeerEmpleadosService } from '../leer-empleados.service';
import { Empleado } from '../empleado';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-empleados',
  templateUrl: './empleados.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empleados.component.css']
})
export class EmpleadosComponent implements OnInit {

  empleados :Empleado[];
  dtOptions :DataTables.Settings = {};
  constructor( private leerService :LeerEmpleadosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: "full_numbers",
      pageLength: 5
    }
    this.getEmpleados();

  }
  getEmpleados() :void{
    this.leerService.getEmpleados().subscribe(empleados => this.empleados = empleados);
  }

}
```

-- empleados.component.html

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover" [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Salario</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
      <th>Imagen</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let empleado of empleados">
    <tr>
      <td>{{empleado.id}}</td>
      <td>{{empleado.employee_name}}</td>
      <td>{{empleado.employee_salary}}</td>
      <td>{{empleado.employee_age}}</td>
      <div *ngIf="empleado.profile_image !=''; else elseImagen">
        <td >{{empleado.profile_image}}</td>
      </div>
      <ng-template #elseImagen>
        <td >No existe imagen</td>
      </ng-template>

    </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

-- app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmpleadosComponent } from './empleados/empleados.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmpleadosComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @AlbertoL.Bonfiglio No, there is no errors in console or in the code

Comment: Have you tried importing Browsermodule?

Comment: @AlbertoL.Bonfiglio it is imported in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more edit to my answer.... 
Actually it's a bug in the implementation of the library. See [github bug report](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1316). 
In any case unless there is a major reason to use this library you can probably use angular material to achieve the same if not better functionality. Syncfusion also has a great component library free for community.